# How to set whitespace-line-colum per mode?

Tags: major-mode, whitespace, whitespace-mode

I'm trying to have `whitespace-line-column` set to `80` in `prog-mode` and `100` in `web-mode`, etc. However when using hooks seems to get ignored, as is always set to `80`.

```el
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-style '(face trailing tab-mark lines-tail))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                             (interactive)
                             (whitespace-mode t)
                             (setq whitespace-line-column 80)))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                            (interactive)
                            (whitespace-mode t)
                            (setq whitespace-line-column 100)))
```

**What is the correct way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to restart whitespace mode for the changes to take effect. Try the following:

```el
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                            (interactive)
                            (whitespace-mode 0)
                            (setq whitespace-line-column 80)
                            (whitespace-mode 1)))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                           (interactive)
                           (whitespace-mode 0)
                           (setq whitespace-line-column 100)
                           (whitespace-mode 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesse I've tried but still stays in 80 =(

Comment: @ZzAntáres that's strange, it worked for me. Please make sure you emptied your hooks before evaluating the code I posted

Comment: oh yes! thank you, I didn't copy your code I was using `(whitespace-mode nil)` for disabling and I now see that you need the `0` otherwise isn't disabled, but yes using your code works! Thanks!.

Comment: I think you can use `(setq-local whitespace-line-column 100)` to avoid affecting the value of the variable in other buffers.